# Use Entity as Attribute of another Entity in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions, eav

I'm going to follow <strike>this tutorial</strike> but my question is.. is it possible to use an EAV Entity as attribute of a new EAV Entity?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: The tutorial that I originally posted is quite messed up and I ended up following [this other tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/) instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
you need to add an attribute for your main entity that has a custom source model.

Let's say your entities are called `Article` and `Author` and you want the `Article` entity to have as attribute and `Author` so when you add/edit and article you can select from a dropdown one of all the authors.

You need to add this in the setup class (`TC_Skeleton_Model_Resource_Setup` from the example you linked) among the other attributes:

```
               'author_id' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Author',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'required' => true, //or false
                    'sort_order' => 10, //what ever
                    'position' => 10,//what ever
                    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL, //or SCOPE_WEBSITE or SCOPE_STORE,
                    'source' => '[module_alias]/source_author', //this needs to be added
                ),
```

Now create the class `[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Source_Author` with this content

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Source_Author extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract{
    protected $_options = null;
    public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = false){
        if (is_null($this->_options)){
            $this->_options = array();
            $authors = Mage::getModel('[module_alias]/author')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('country');
            foreach ($authors as $author) {
                $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => $author->getId(),
                    'label' => $author->getName(). ' - '.$author->getCountry()
                );
            }
        }
        $options = $this->_options;
        if ($withEmpty) {
            array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''));
        }
        return $options;
    }
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);

        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if ($item['value'] == $value) {
                return $item['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

in addition, [you can find here](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html) and example on how to add an attribute with a custom source model to the products. If your entity is EAV it should work the same. The most important part is the `getAllOptions` method in the class mentioned above. you can do anything in there as long as you return an array of values.

Also [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9) might help. It can build on the fly the files you need for your entities (EAV or flat) and it also allows you to establish relations between entities (one to many or many to many). In your case you need a one to many relation.

---

<sub>I am involved in the development of the extension, but it's free for everyone to use or change.</sub>

Comment: WHAT?! SHAMELESS SELF PROMOTION!
jk/ cool answer :)

Comment: @Sander I have nothing to be ashamed :)

Comment: One thing. In your example, imagine that "Author" has an attribute called "country". Would it be possible to display "Author - Country" as the dropdown option in the Article Entity?

Comment: @VDD I modified the code to fit your needs.

Comment: @Marius how can access the source model from other extensions? I'm doing an adminhtml extension with  select fieldsets for all these attributes of the new EAV Entity. I've tried   $fieldset->addField('author', 'select', array(
   'label'     => $this->__('Author'),
   'class'     => 'required-entry',
   'required'  => true,
   'name'      => 'author',
   'value'  => '1',
   'values' => Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_module/source_author)->getAllOptions(),));  but I get the error Invalid method Namespace_Module_Model_Author::addFieldToSelect(Array ( [0] => name ) )

Comment: If I use 'values' => Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_module/source_author')->getOptionText(),   I get the error Warning: Missing argument 1 for Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Source_Brand::getOptionText(), called in /home/public_html/website/app/code/local/Namespace/Module2/Block/Adminhtml/Admin/Edit/Tab/Entity.php on line 47 and defined in /home/public_html/website/app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Source/Author.php on line 28

Comment: In those errors that I'm getting, replace addFieldToSelect with addAttributeToSelect, sorry for the typo.

Comment: I've also tried 'values' => Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_module/source_author)->getOptionText('name'),   and it also says Invalid method Namespace_Module_Model_Author::addAttributeToSelect(Array ( [0] => name ) )

Comment: not sure I understand...why are you using `getOptionText`?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to display the values of those attributes with external sources in dropdowns in a form, but I don't know how to achieve it. I also get the same error if I don't use the function getOptionText. I'm quite lost with this and I'd really appreaciate if you could help me, please

Comment: use `getAllOptions` instead of `getOptionText`

Comment: If I use getAllOptions it throws the error Invalid method Namespace_Module_Model_Author::addAttributeToSelect(Array ( [0] => name ) )

Comment: Then replace `addAttributeToSelect` with `addFieldToSelect`. The first one is for eav entities the second one is for flat entities.

Comment: This is driving me nuts... I get the same error.. :( Invalid method Namespace_Module_Model_Author::addFieldToSelect(Array ( [0] => name ) )

Comment: @VDD. Ok. My bad. I missed something. Sorry. There should be an `->getCollection()` before `addAttributeToSelect` or `addFieldToSelect`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Marius you're the best. All sorted.

Comment: @Marius could you please help me with [this other question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60668/saving-values-to-new-eav-entity-magento) which is related to this one? I'm really struggling with it and I don't know where to look in the code to solve it. Thanks.