# Saving values to new EAV Entity Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, adminhtml, extensions, eav

I posted [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60267/use-entity-as-attribute-of-another-entity-in-magento/60270?noredirect=1#comment81222_60270) the other day and I've successfully created a new EAV entity with other Entities as Attributes.

This new Entity is called Result and has Championship, Event, Athlete, Brand, Rank, Order and Score as Attributes. Championship, Event, Athlete and Brand are flat tables entities themselves.

Now the problem that I have is that I'm developing a new extension and I need to save attributes and values to this new Entity. This Adminhtml extension has a tabbed form and the code that I have in my app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Result/Edit/Tab/Result.php is as follows:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Result_Edit_Tab_Result
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    /**
     * Add the form fields
     *
     * @return Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Result_Edit_Tab_Result
     *
     */

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('result');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'edit_form',
            array(
                'legend' => $this->__('Result Setup')
            )
        );

        /*if (Mage::registry('current_result')->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'entity_id',
                'label',
                array(
                    'label' => $this->__('ID:'),
                )
            );
        }*/


        $fieldset->addField('championship', 'select', array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Select Championship'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'championship',
            'value'     => '',
            'values' => Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_modulethatcreatedtheeaventity/source_championship')->getAllOptions(),

        ));

        $fieldset->addField('event', 'select', array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Select Event'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'event',
            'value'     => '',
            'values' => Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_modulethatcreatedtheeaventity/source_event')->getAllOptions(),

        ));

        $fieldset->addField('athlete', 'select', array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Select Athlete'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'athlete',
            'value'     => '',
            'values' => Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_modulethatcreatedtheeaventity/source_athlete')->getAllOptions(),

        ));

        $fieldset->addField('brand', 'select', array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Select Brand'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'brand',
            'value'     => '',
            'values' => Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_modulethatcreatedtheeaventity/source_brand')->getAllOptions(),

        ));

        $fieldset->addField('rank', 'select', array(
            'label'     => $this->__('Select Medal'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'rank',
            'value'  => '1',
            'values' => array('-1'=>'Select the medal...','1' => 'Gold','2' => 'Silver', '3' => 'Bronze'),

        ));

        $fieldset->addField(
            'order',
            'text',
            array(
                'label' => $this->__('Event order'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => false,
                'name' => 'order',
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'score',
            'text',
            array(
                'label' => $this->__('Score'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'score',
            )
        );



        $form->addValues($this->_getFormData());

        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getFormData()
    {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData();

        if (!$data && Mage::registry('current_result')->getData()) {
            $data = Mage::registry('current_result')->getData();
        }

        return (array) $data;
    }
}
```

The grid works but it's empty. When I click on Add New Result, I can successfully access the New/Edit page and see the values in the dropdowns, as well as getting the success message when I click on save, but no Attributes are being saved to the Result EAV entity, just the entity_id, which increases every time and when I go back to the grid I see a new row with the new entity_id and all the other fields blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.